# Could smoking cause erectile dysfunction?

Tags: physiology, sexuality, smoking, tobacco, erectile-dysfunction

I was told that smoking 'menthol' cigarettes could cause erectile dysfunction. But I don't know how much of this is true so I wanted to know how much of this is true...

Here is an example of the claim:

> [image]

Source: Tobacco Free Florida, via: [Guts of a Burglar blog](http://www.gutsofaburglar.com/sledgehammer-advertising/observations)

EDIT: Does smoking any type of Cigarettes cause ED or is it just some types or brands like 'Menthol' , 'Black' etc...???

Comment: [Interesting..](http://www.webmd.com/erectile-dysfunction/news/20030307/smoking-can-lead-to-erectile-dysfunction)

Comment: I have heard more than once it explained that smoking reduces bloodflow, I think it's because nicotine expands the blood veins, but don't quote me on that, I am just taking that from mind. With a worse blood flow generally the erections will be suffering.

Comment: @Adel make a full answer of that.

Comment: @Oddthinking Thank you sir for the edit and other data...

Comment: @Wertilq - The problem I personally have with WebMD is that they're terrible at reporting their references (in this case they cite "News release, American Heart Association" - lame!). You'd think a website with a "sciencey" sounding name would understand scientific rigor. Thankfully it wasn't hard to find the *actual* research!

Comment: @Wertilq - all stimulants generally *constrict* blood vessels, which leads to reduced blood flow. Now, menthol vs any other form of cigarette?  Not sure why that would be, but I'm not up to speed on cigarette varieties.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Yes**

Most of the information on this subject appears to come from the work of Pourmand G, Alidaee MR, Rasuli S, Maleki A, Mehrsai A. at the Urology Research Center, [Tehran University of Medical Sciences](http://www.tums.ac.ir/?lang=en), Tehran, Iran

> The severity of ED correlated significantly with the level of exposure to smoking
>   <sub>Source: [Do cigarette smokers with erectile dysfunction benefit from stopping?: a prospective study.](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1464-410X.2004.05162.x/abstract)</sub>

They conclude:

> There is a strong association between the intensity of cigarette smoking and degree of ED. Stopping cigarette smoking can improve ED in a considerable proportion of smokers. Age and the severity of ED before stopping are inversely related to the chance of improvement.

The Authors of the study make no reference to the *type* of cigarette smoked, they used the [pack-years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pack_year) measure to estimate the level of exposure to smoking.

> We assessed whether there was a significant correlation between pack-years and the severity of ED

Comment: Improve ED sounds bad isn't it? Maybe diminish ED? Btw I know it is a citation...