# Does Smoking/Boozing Cause Erectile Dysfunction?

Tags: smoking, erectile-dysfunction

I have heard many different things from people about ED (impotence) issue. I am a chain smoker also drink a lot and i am experiencing ED problems from past few months. I am not able to get hard in bed. Can smoking really causes Impotency.

Comment: The part about whether smoking causes ED has already been answered on [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15893/could-smoking-cause-erectile-dysfunction?rq=1) which, curiously enough, you've already posted an answer on yourself.

Comment: We are not qualified to give specific health advice.

Comment: This article should answer your question.  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0090429502021027 Alcohol: no.  Heavy Smoking: yes.